# How to toggle the form that lives in the same scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a bit confused about a situation I have, basically I need to toggle a form with the click of a button, without toggling all the forms on the page.

If I have a structure like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in cart"> 
        ... lots of elements ... 
        <button data-toggle data-target="myForm">Toggle form</button>
        ... some container ...
            <!-- deep nested form -->
            <form class="myForm"></form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this directive:

```
core.directive('toggle', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

            element.on('click', function() {
                $('.' + attrs.target).stop().slideToggle(100);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

How do I make it so that the button won't toggle every single form in every repeated element? I somehow need to start from the li that the button resides in and then toggle the form, but exactly how can I do that in an efficient way? I was thinking about passing in an isolated scope to the directive and then use that to somehow traverse down the DOM structure and toggle the form, but it feels like that isn't even possible?

What should I do to solve my problem?

Comment: what's the relationship between the button and the form?

Comment: @sahbeewah The button just makes the form slide out. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Instead of a class `myForm` I would create a form ID `'#myForm'+i` where  `i` increments with each element (item) added.

Comment: @mccannf But you can only have one ID on a page so it wouldn't work since there are multiple forms.

Comment: @mccannf Well that is a solution, but it feels a bit dirty don't you think?

Comment: DOM relationship. All you need to do, is rather than specify the selector as the general class selector (.selector), use the form's container as context. So assuming the container happens to be a div that comes after the button: ```$(this).next('div').find('.' + attrs.target)``` ...

Comment: Personally I would only use one form since they are repeating elements with same structure. No need for jQuery to do this.

Comment: Using the `context` argument of `jQuery()` may be the simplest way as it is, i.e. `$('.' + attrs.target, element).stop().slideToggle(100);`, but this is probably an abuse of jQuery in Angular - see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

Comment: "li" is the container for both "button" and "form" elements. So you need: 
$(event.target).closest('li').find('form').stop().slideToggle(100);

Comment: No one gonna post as an actual answer?